# Usar class de div em validação js

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho uma validação de login em js que gera um alerta:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var mensagem = "<?php echo (isset( $_SESSION['erroLogin'])?  $_SESSION['erroLogin'] : "false");?>";
    <?php unset($_SESSION['erroLogin']);?>
    if (mensagem != "false") {
        alert(mensagem);
    }
</script>
```

Porém gostaria de usar um alerta personalizado que tenho como exemplo em um button

```
<button class="md-btn" data-message="mensagem de alerta" data-pos="bottom-right">alerta</button>
```

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Queres que o alert seja chamado quando clicas no botão?

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<button class="md-btn validate" data-message="mensagem de alerta" data-pos="bottom-right">alerta</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
var mensagem = "<?php echo (isset( $_SESSION['erroLogin'])? $_SESSION['erroLogin'] : "false ");?>"; <?php unset($_SESSION['erroLogin']);?>

$('.validate').click(function() {
  var message = $(this).data('message');
  if (!mensagem) {
    alert(message)
  }
});
```

Não tenho a certeza se era isto que querias mas aqui vai.

O `var message = $(this).data('message');` vai apanhar tudo o que puseres dentro da data-message e mostrar como alert se existir algum